# Explicitly create cached user/password for SVN

Tags: svn, authentication, passwords

is there a method for svn to explicitly create the cached name/password settings for a user and doing nothing else ? Name/password settings will be given via a dialog, while svn is probably installed just in the step before.

I need that as a step in a workspace installer, which will later make use of svn.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t, but if you just run any command, for example `svn info http://path/to/repos --username foo --password bar --non-interactive`, then that should cache the information.